# Android can not connect to wifi already connect before

Tags: android, android-wifi

Step1: Open android wifi system setting, connect to wifi A and leaver (not forget)

Step2: Open app and connect to wifi A, function `wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)` always return -1

If I forget wifi A and go to app connect then it will connect success.

If wifi A already connect before, in Android 8 and below `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` can return this wifi A so I can get networkId to enable this, but in Android 10 is not return anything, Android 9 not tested because I don't have.

I'm not Android developer so I just try my best, any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because WifiManager is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()).

From what I've understood you want to connect to a WiFi network, [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build()) is the new method.

Comment: Thanks, I try new method, it's can connect successful but no internet connection, don't know why :(
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63469721/2749735

Comment: If my answer worked you should mark it as best answer by clicking on the check on the left. If Android tells you that there is no internet connection it's probably a config issue for your router, not something related with the app.

Comment: If I connect manually by go to android system setting then it's normal but when I connect using code it's say no internet connection, I think config for router is fine.

Comment: `If my answer worked you should mark it as best answer `. No. As tomorrow there can still come better answers. Moreover one does not ask for points for oneself.

Comment: Can't he just change it? :/ (if better answers appear)

Comment: Moreover @blackapps from the help centre: `Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally.`. I'm not asking for reputation, instead telling some people who might not know what the best answer is, how to actually use it.