# Android 10 connect to specific wifi but no internet connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0

I connect to wifi by code below, It can connect successful but no internet connection (android show icon network with x), don't know why.

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .setSsid(ssid)
    .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
    .build();

NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
        .build();

connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
        super.onAvailable(network);
        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
    }
};
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
```

Comment: In onAvailable set the network on wifi. `network.`. Your compiler will let you choose the function which i forgot the name of.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain more, I still don't know what function need to use.
I searching a lot and found that link may problem come from android 10: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744.
Still don't know how to workaround it.

Comment: I forgot the name. But if you just type network. in Android Studio you are presented with a lot of functions to choose from. Which one to choose should be clear then. Now does AS act as i said?

Comment: Here the list function of Network: https://i.imgur.com/yWvQmD5.png
can you see it, thanks.

Comment: Its a bit different sorry but its all here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227000/android-10-wifi-connection-cant-reach-gateway?noredirect=1#comment112099948_63227000  `connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);`

Comment: Now I know that wifi connected and only app can access other will be not, the system still show icon wifi no internet connection but it is ok.
For continue connect other wifi need disconnect current wifi first.

Answer (score 2):

Change your network request

```
val networkRequest: NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                    .build()
```

But I got an issue when I called to request to add a network again, networkCallback called in onUnavailable, and nothing to do.